# Convert a String date to Long Date and update rows in derby database

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

In my java application I am trying to update some rows with long date value. I've pasted my codes below. Here the table name is `"CASHSELL"` The columns are `"DATE VARCHAR(20)` and `"DATES BIGINT"`.

```
 String query = "SELECT DATE, DATES FROM CASHSELL";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

  try{
      conn = new connection().db();  
   stmtt =   conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
   rs = stmtt.executeQuery(query);
   while (rs.next()){

       String dat = rs.getString("DATE");
       Date d = (Date) sdf.parse(dat);
       long longDate = d.getTime();

       rs.updateLong("DATES", longDate);
       rs.updateRow();

       conn.commit();
   }   

  }
  catch(SQLException | ParseException ex){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
  }
  finally{try{rs.close(); conn.close(); stmtt.close();}catch(SQLException ex){} }
```

This method is not working anyway. What is the mistake I am making here? There is no error message also? Am I missing something? Or is it not the proper way to update with JDBC? Is there any other way, so that I can Update 1,00,000 rows by converting the string date to long date?

I am working in Derby Database.

Comment: "is not working" is hopelessly vague - what's happening? Are you sure the format is really "dd-MM-yyyy" instead of the more common "yyyy-MM-dd"?

Comment: you said to update some rows with long date but i do not see where clause in your query.So all the rows will be effected

Comment: I've to update all the rows with different values. I think "rs.updateRow()" updates a single row. So, I am trying to execute the query within a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a loop or the `SELECT` at all.

```
update CASHSELL
  set dates = {fn TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_SECOND, timestamp ('1970-01-01 00:00:00'), "DATE") } * 1000;
```

`TIMESTAMPDIFF` will return the number of seconds between 1970-01-01 and the value of the `DATE` column. As the `long` value of a `java.util.Date` is the number of *milli* seconds since then, you need to multiply the result with 1000.

So the above statement will update the `dates` column to the corresponding long value of the `DATE` column.

But I don't understand *why* you want to do that. Storing a derived value is usually not a good idea. You can always calculate that value "on-the-fly" when retrieving the data from the table.

Btw: `DATE` is a horrible name for a column. Firstly because it's a reserved word and can lead to a lot of confusion. Secondly because it does not document the data model. Is that a "due date", a "valid from date", a "valid until date", a "birthdate" ....

And `DATES` is just as confusing. You should have named it `milliseconds` or something similar.